# SQL Local DB Connection on Microsoft SilverLight

Tags: sql, vb.net, silverlight

Using VB.NET, I can connect to a local SQL database easily, but, trying to get more advanced graphical features, I started using SilverLight for VB.NET, and so i got this problem.
Is it possible to connect a local database, and it must be SQL, with SilverLight for VB.NET?
It must be Out Of Browser too, i'm doing a Desktop App.

If there's no really way to do it, how can i make a more beatiful system, as I don't want to make the same old windows style.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access a db with Silverlight. As to how, the same ways you'd do it without SL really. Personally I use EntityFramework, and create a model from my database. Then I operate on that model using the context generated.

It doesn't matter if the db is local or remote, the methods are the same - they are just connection strings after all.

Comment: But how can i possibly do it? On VB, i use OLEDB, but on SL, there's no such class to make that connection, how could i possibly connect it?

Comment: *Entity Framework*. It works with any .NET version from 3.5 onwards. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use it, so I won't insult your intelligence by posting a link I found just by doing a Google search.